# R sommer package - version out of date message

Tags: r, r-package

Using the sommer package quite extensively I often get messages telling my version is out of date even though I'm using the latest version of the package. This can be especially annoying when using sommer in some sort of loop.
Is there a way to avoid these messages?

Answer (score 1):

Hi BartJan welcome to SO!

Have you tried calling the library with `quietly = TRUE`?

```
library(sommer,quietly = TRUE)
```

If that doesn't work, you can make R suppress all messages and warnings:

```
suppressMessages(suppressWarnings(require(xyz)))
```